# Failed to send push notification by amazon pinpoint, create pinpint object by aws-sdk (Amazon Pinpoint can not create Object)

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore, push-notification, amazon-sns, aws-pinpoint

I'm developing an app using react native and aws amplify. I implemented a push notification using AWS SNS, Pinpoint, and Google Firebase and successfully tested it on the Amazon pinpoint test messaging page(From the Firebase test page is also successful). However, when I tried to send the push notification with my code, I encountered a problem. Below is the code to send the push notification.

```
"aws-sdk": "^2.1435.0",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.72.3",
```

---

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const SendPushNoti = async () => {
    const messageRequest = CreateMessageRequest();
    AWS.config.update({ region: region });

    const pinpoint = new AWS.Pinpoint(); // <<<<<<<< error

    const params = {
        ApplicationId: applicationId,
        MessageRequest: messageRequest,
    };
    pinpoint.sendMessages(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else console.dir(data);
    });
};

const CreateMessageRequest = () => {
    // make a message
}
```

---

I got the below error from the `const pinpoint = new AWS.Pinpoint();` line.

**Error message:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined error.
```

If I make an SNS object as a test, It was successful.(`const sns = new AWS.SNS();`)
And when I print AWS (`console.log(AWS);`) there is a SNS but Pinpoint is not.

`"SNS": [Function anonymous],`

I don't know what to do. Does anybody help me, please?